# Enabling HYP Mode on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot, raspbian-stretch

I'm running Raspbian Stretch on a Raspberry Pi 3 (Model B) and I want to enable HYP mode. Problem is all of the resources I find when searching for enabling HYP mode on a Pi 3 returns resources on how to enable HYP mode on Pi 2.

How do I enable HYP mode on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike the Raspberry Pi 2 which is based on ARMv7 architecture, Raspberry Pi 3 is based on ARMv8 (more precisely, on ARMv8-A) which solves the hypervisor support in a different way.

According to [this article](https://www.embedded.com/design/mcus-processors-and-socs/4461129/Understanding-virtualization-facilities-in-the-ARMv8-processor-architecture) and the [ARM Cortex-A Series Programmer’s Guide for ARMv8-A](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0024a/CIHGCIDG.html), it uses another privilege level called *EL2* (Exception Level 2) and does not require to run in a special run mode like HYP on ARMv7.